# How to use layout_column_wrap() inside a quarto document

Tags: r, quarto, bslib

I'd like to make use of `bslib::layout_column_wrap()` inside a Quarto doc, but columns do not wrap as expected .

For example, this:

````r
---
title: "test"
---

```{r}

bslib::layout_column_wrap(
  width = 1/2,
  bslib::value_box(1, 1),
  bslib::value_box(2, 2)
)

```
````

produces:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bslib::layout_column_wrap` is using `grid-template-columns` css property, which needs `display: grid`.

````
---
title: "test"
---

```{r}
#| classes: col_wrap
bslib::layout_column_wrap(
  width = 1/2,
  bslib::value_box(1, 1),
  bslib::value_box(2, 2)
)
```

```{css, echo=FALSE}
div.col_wrap div.bslib-column-wrap {
  display: grid;
}
```
````

[image: bslib two columns layout]

Answer (score 1):

You can pass "d-grid" to the class argument of `bslib::layout_column_wrap()`:

````r
---
title: "test"
---

```{r}
bslib::layout_column_wrap(
  width = 1/2,
  class = "d-grid",
  bslib::value_box(1, 1),
  bslib::value_box(2, 2)
)
```
````

[image]

This changes the default `display: block` to `display: grid` in the `div` produced by the quarto code chunk.